# single constructor that permits the specification of a data value, or a data value and left child, or a data value and left child and right child

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

So for school in c++ part of a project is to make a single constructor that can construct a node with a data value, a node with a data value AND a left child, or a node with a data value AND left child AND right child. I've tried to Google it and I'm sure its a simple convention, I just haven't been able to find anything.

How do you write a constructor that uses parameters if they are there, and ignores them otherwise?

something like:

```
public TreeNode(T data, #TreeNode left, #TreeNode right)
```

where the # denotes "might not be there"

Comment: You are probably looking for [constructor overloading.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330296/constructor-overloading-in-c). If you check the answer in the link you will see that the class may have multiples constructors with different parameters.

Comment: More like default-values. (Use `= initializer`) at the end of the argument. BTW: You can only default an argument if there is no non-defaulted argument following.

Comment: Like in python? He can always initialize `left` and/or `right` to null in the others constructors. Although, I dont know if thats a good practice.

Comment: @wendelbsilva If those are truly optional (and in a tree they *must* be -- if child nodes are required then you can only have infinite trees!) then using a null pointer or some other sentinel "no value" value is not only correct, but is the *only way* to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options: constructor overloading, or default values for the optional parameters.

I am going to assume that the `left` and `right` constructor arguments should actually be pointers to nodes since you are building a tree.  (I would suggest using `std::unique_ptr` here but I'm going to just use raw pointers in this answer since it's not important to the answer to this particular question.  However, I would strongly suggest investigating `std::unique_ptr` since it will mean you won't need a custom destructor to delete child nodes; the smart pointer destructor will take care of that for you.)

## Constructor overloading

Simply define multiple constructors that take all of the combinations you need:

```
public:
    explicit TreeNode(T data);
    TreeNode(T data, TreeNode * left);
    TreeNode(T data, TreeNode * left, TreeNode * right);
```

You need to implement each constructor separately, but note that you can call one constructor from another using the constructor's initializer list.

## Default values

```
public:
    explicit TreeNode(T data, TreeNode * left = nullptr, TreeNode * right = nullptr);
```

(Substitute `NULL` for `nullptr` if you are not using C++11.)

In this case, `left` and `right` are optional parameters that will be "filled in" using the supplied defaults if they are omitted.  (Note that you cannot omit only `left`; if you omit `left` you must also omit `right`.)

When actually implementing the constructor you do not need to specify the default values again:

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(T data, TreeNode * left, TreeNode * right)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

In both cases you will be able to call the constructor with one, two, or three arguments.

Comment: Actually, for minimal dependencies, use plain `0`, neither `NULL` (needs a header) nor `nullptr` (needs C++11).

Comment: @Deduplicator 0 isn't very semantic; in my own code I would much prefer to use something symbolic instead.

Comment: Ah, well. Where it is blatantly obvious that the `0` is a nullpointer-constant, I consider using anything else excessively loquacious. A matter of taste. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Deduplicator That is a truly fantastic word.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since the assignment requires a single constructor, it seems default values will work great.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you can provide a default for any function-argument you want, as long as it is not followed by arguments without defaults:

Needs 3 arguments:

```
int f(int a, int b, int c);
```

Needs 2 arguments, the third is defaulted if not supplied:

```
int g(int a, int b, int c = f(1,2,3));
```

Illegal: Cannot provide a default for argument 2, as an argument without default follows:

```
int h(int a, int b = 0, int c);
```

Be aware that a constructor which can be called with only one argument is a user-defined conversion.
So define it `explicit` unless you are really sure what you are doing.

Comment: +1 for `explicit`, stole this for my answer too... :|