# Problems with constructors

Tags: c++, oop

**Introduction**

I'm really new in C++. I've started read some books and search some stuff in Internet. But my main problem is debug C++ code and the basics.

So, I want create a new class, called ClientTcp.
If create the object with no arguments, the IP and the Port shall be standard (127.0.0.1:8000).

I've read this question [Constructor Overloading in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330296/constructor-overloading-in-c).

So I created this code:

**ClientTcp.h file.**

```
class ClientTcp{
    public:
        // non arguments, create loopback connection
        ClientTcp();

        ClientTcp(std::string, std::string);

        virtual ~ClientTcp();
    protected:
    private:
        std::string ip_, port_;
};
```

**ClientTcp.cpp file**

```
#include "ClientTcp.h"

ClientTcp::ClientTcp(){
    ip_ = "127.0.0.1";
    port_ = "8000";
}

ClientTcp::ClientTcp(std::string ip, std::string port){
    ip_.assign(ip);
    port_.assign(port);
}

ClientTcp::~ClientTcp(){
    //dtor
}
```

**Main.cpp file**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "json.hpp"
#include <ClientTcp.h>

std::string cip, cport;
cip = "127.0.0.1";
cport = "9510";
ClientTcp c(cip, cport);
```

**Problem**
It seems perfect, but I have a ridiculous error that I can't understand.

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token|
```

**Line:** This error is present in `ClientTcp(string, string);` line.

Comment: Did you `#include<string>`?

Comment: The code in `main.cpp` needs to go inside a function. You can only have declarations outside a function.

Comment: I was thinking that include in main.cpp was enough. Thanks

Comment: Upvoted for completeness of the question, closevoted as "simple typographical error or otherwise unlikely to help future readers". ;-)

Comment: @Urbester Well if you included `<string>` in all your .cpp files before you include your own header, that would be enough. (But don't rely on that, it would be terrible style!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your declaration of `ClientTcp(std::string,std::string);`, a definition of `std::string` needs to be available, regardless of whether you include it in some other translation unit.

The fix is to `#include<string>` in `ClientTcp.h`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `#include<string>`,  this might be the reason.